# Can Dispatcher.Invoke ever return before executing the method?

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, dispatcher

I am debugging a weird bug where a worker thread is dispatching several methods into the main thread: e.g.

```
private void WokerThread()
{
    var dispatcher = Application.Current.Dispatcher;
    while (true) {
        Property1 = new Stuff();
        Property2 = new Stuff();
        Property3 = new Stuff();
        Property4 = new Stuff();

        dispatcher.Invoke(() => OnPropertyChanged("Property1")); // method1
        dispatcher.Invoke(() => OnPropertyChanged("Property2"));
        dispatcher.Invoke(() => OnPropertyChanged("Property3"));
        dispatcher.Invoke(() => OnPropertyChanged("Property4")); // method4
        // Some sleep goes here
    }
}
```

That's all working fine except when a certain data structure that is bound to a GUI control gets tremendous and then the GUI thread starts to slow down a bit while rendering.

In which case I find the `WorkerThread` waiting on `method1` to return, while the main thread crashes while trying to execute `method4`. The crash is because some data is not ready in that instance, which is not our issue here.

The question is: can the line `method4` return and `WorkerThread` continue execution before the method is executed in case the GUI thread is busy?

Is that why I find the GUI executing `method4` while the `WorkerThread` is waiting on `method1` to return?

Comment: Is method 4 by chance async? Dispatcher.Invoke will wait for the end, but async methods are compiled to a series of continuations, so if you call an async method without awaiting it, it will seemingly return at the first await.

Comment: methods 1 to 4 are actually calling `OnPropertyChanged` on some properties so the actual execution of those 4 methods is inside WPF responding to bound properties been changed. I've updated the question.

Comment: Maybe you are looking for [Dispatcher.BeginInvoke](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.begininvoke(v=vs.110).aspx) which works asynchronously, whereas Dispatcher.Invoke works synchronously.

Comment: Why do you invoke 4 times instead of one time and calling 4 times property changed in the delegate?

Comment: This is a legacy code I am trying to fix a bug into, I need to understand what is happening before fixing it. The doing much more, I have just reduced it to the minimum that explains the problem.

Comment: Please note that the binding operations are executed by `Dispatcher` with a lower priority than the user code. So when you call `Dispatcher.Invoke`, the `Dispatcher` tries to execute that method with highest priority. If that method updates some bindings (even indirectly), these updates are queued with lower priority. But since you call `Dispatcher.Invoke` 4 times consequently, it is possible that the bindings updates of the first call will be only processed after the 4th call is finished. Since you're firing the `PropertyChanged` event, I suppose that the bindings are involved in your logic.